# Unable to read "BLOOD GLUCOSE" using rest api | Google fit

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-api, google-fitness-api

I am trying to **fetch my blood-glucose** data using ***Google fit rest API*** and using ***OAuth 2.0 Playground.***

I've manually inserted data in the google fit app (**fit app > Browse > Vitals > Blood glucose**)
and tried to fetch it using REST API and OAuth 2.0 Playground using the following request parameters.

> `scope:  .../auth/fitness.blood_glucose.read`

Request Parameters

> ```
> POST /fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate HTTP/1.1 
> Host: www.googleapis.com 
> Content-length: 193 
> Content-type: application/JSON 
> Authorization: Bearer y**
> ```

> ```
> { 
>  "aggregateBy": [{"dataTypeName": "com.google.blood_glucose"}],
>  "bucketByTime": { "durationMillis": 86400000 }, 
>  "startTimeMillis": 1663180200000, "endTimeMillis": 1665772200000 
> }
> ```

I didn't get any errors but neither I got any data for the same.
below is the sample response.

> ```
> ​{
>   "bucket": [
>     {
>       "startTimeMillis": "1663180200000",
>       "endTimeMillis": "1663266600000",
>       "dataset": [
>         {
>           "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.blood_glucose.summary:com.google.android.gms:aggregated",
>           "point": []
>         }
>       ]
>     },
>      {
>       "startTimeMillis": "1665685800000",
>       "endTimeMillis": "1665772200000",
>       "dataset": [
>         {
>           "dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.blood_glucose.summary:com.google.android.gms:aggregated",
>           "point": []
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

***All the points are empty even though I can see them in my data in google fit.***

The issue is persisting particulary for blood glucose while the rest Health data points are working fine.

Comment: May be data is not synced from Google Fit app with backend yet? Is the other data instantly returned by REST API after updating in Google Fit app?

Comment: Data is Synced from the Google Fit app, I have tried uninstalling the app and then re-installing the app again the data was there.
But I am not getting data using the REST API.

Comment: I've also tried for blood pressure same thing data is added manually but in that case, I am getting data from google fit REST API and OAuth 2.0 Playground.
This issue only occurs for blood glucose.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that there's no documentation available to read blood glucose records in Fit Android/Rest API. You may try Google's new Health Connect API, it supports BloodGlucoseRecord

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/health/connect/client/records/package-summary#classes

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34622522)